# Compare two file content in Python 3.5 and derive output message for everyline

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, compare

I've two files, derive an output in Python 3.5.

The test1/2 log file contains a time ordered list
    F 13885 huuyyyy

This is the output format that I've to write.

```
PNkjjjjL 14200632000dddw00
```

Comment: check `pandas` to munge the data. If you use `xlrd`, then the files are Excel files instead of space separated plain text?

Comment: I agree with you. Please ignore those two files of loading for now. I'm mostly looking how to parse every line and compare them.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of munging the data using python and compare two files ?

Comment: it is unclear to me how you get from the first 2 files to the output

Comment: Okay. Let me explain again. So basically this is what I'm trying to do - I need to read test1 and test2 file and next split file content by space in every line and get millisecond timestamp (second from left in data set) and compare that timestamp with other file every line timestamp and if it matches just print a message. How can I do it in python 3.5 ?

Comment: Read them in pandas and do an inner join on the timestamp

Comment: I guess the symbol matters too?

Comment: Yes, Simbol matters when we derive the calculated output. But most importantly the portion I'm looking for help is how to read two files and slit content by space and next compare ( I'm totally new to Python ) Can you please give me a sample if you can. Not necessary has to be accurate.

Comment: I could able to read test1 and test2 file using pandas and able to join them. But the part I couldn't able to figure out how to determine output column 5 (i.e dataframe1 Price *  dataframe1 size) when dataframe1 indicator is "B"

Comment: I would do that before the join `dataFrame1['mark'] = dataFrame1['Price'] * dataFrame1['Fill size']).loc[dataFrame1['Side indicator'] == 'B']`

Comment: after the merge is also possible off course: `merged['mark'] = merged['Price'] * merged['Fill size']).loc[merged['Side indicator'] == 'B']`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. I've modified the solution. Can you please take a look at the code and let me know if I need to modify anything to improve the code ? As I'm new to Python, I thought to check with you. Thank you.